# Why does sourcing give a syntax error when bash executes the code fine?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

The script is quite simple:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [[ 0 ]]; then
   echo foo
fi
```

The error manifests as:

```
$ source ./sample.sh
./sample.sh:2: parse error near `]]'
```

But notice that `bash` is able to execute the script just fine:

```
$ /bin/bash ./sample.sh
foo

$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

From the bash docs:

```
[[ expression ]]
   Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on  the  evaluation  of  the
   conditional  expression expression.  Expressions are composed of
   the primaries described  below  under  CONDITIONAL  EXPRESSIONS.

   ...

CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
   Conditional  expressions  are  used  by the [[ compound command and the
   test and [ builtin commands to test file attributes and perform  string
   and  arithmetic comparisons.  Expressions are formed from the following
   unary or binary primaries.

   ...

   string
   -n string
          True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

Note that the syntax error manifests with either `0` or `"0"` as the expression.

Adding an operator (eg, `-n`) resolves the parse error, but it doesn't seem like it should be necessary from the docs and also doesn't explain why `bash` evaluates it just fine.

Comment: Post output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: your shell is `zsh`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your shell isn't bash. When you run `source ./sample.sh` it runs the script in the context of the current shell, whatever that is, ignoring the `#!/bin/bash` hash-bang line.

By the way, what is `if [[ 0 ]]` intended to do? It's somewhat nonsensical. `[[ 0 ]]` is equivalent to `[[ -n 0 ]]` which checks if `0` is a non-empty string. This is guaranteed to be true.

To write a simple true or false check, I would instead write:

```
if true; then
```

or

```
if false; then
```

Comment: I don't get the latter part; why write a check at all?

Comment: If you were temporarily hard coding the condition, I suppose. That's about it. `while true; do` is more useful.

Comment: The `if [[ 0 ]]` is simplified from a larger script that looked more like this: `if [[ $(grep foo.txt | sed ...) ]]; then`. Now, that's still wrong (ought to be `if grep foo.txt | sed ...; then`, but 1) it wasn't my code and 2) it didn't seem like a syntax error in any case. Indeed, `bash` is able to source it just fine.

I completely overlooked the fact that it was `zsh` sourcing the file. Thanks for the facepalm. =)